# String Join How to Ignore Both Empty and LineBreaks

Tags: c#, string, removing-whitespace

This is example code.

I'm able to join all the strings and separate them with spaces.

If the string is `Empty`, the join will ignore, preventing a double space.

How do I also ignore linebreaks `\n` in the same `ColorList.Where()` parameters?

```
string red = "Red";
string blue = "Blue";
string yellow = "\n\n";
string green = string.Empty;

List<string> ColorList = new List<string>()
{
    red,
    blue,
    yellow,
    green
};

string colors = string.Join(" ", ColorList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `.Where(s => !s.Contains("\n"))` to your query as:

```
string red = "Red";
string blue = "Blue";
string yellow = "\n\n";
string green = string.Empty;

 List<string> ColorList = new List<string>()
{
    red,
    blue,
    yellow,
    green
};

string colors = string.Join(" ", ColorList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Where(s => !s.Contains("\n")));
```

Comment: I would change `string green = string.Empty;` to `string green = null;`

Comment: then add other `Where` as `.Where(s => s != null)` to query handle that

Comment: It works, thanks. I used `!s.Equals("\n\n")`. So if it's a standalone LineBreak without any other text.

Comment: This would also exclude `red\n`

Comment: yes if you want to exactly remove `\n\n` then use `.Where(s => !s.Contains("\n\n"))`

Comment: in generally you can use many `Where` in your code to deal with your goal in the result of query

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

and also Trim any white space for the rest.

```
string red = "Red";
string blue = "Blue";
string yellow = "\n\n";
string green = string.Empty;
string black = null;

var ColorList = new List<string>()
{
    red,
    blue,
    yellow,
    green,
    black
};

//Red Blue
string colors = string.Join(" ", 
    ColorList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Select(s => s.Trim())
);
```

This will safely ignore or null, empty, or items with only white spaces. It will also remove any stray white spaces on remaining items.